# Requests module throwing OpenSSL.SSL.Error

Tags: python, rest, ssl, curl, python-requests

I'm using a REST API from [euronext.com](http://www.euronext.com), to go any further I need to verify the server certificate and send my own client certificate through the module requests.

I already did some testing with curl, both .crt/.pem files were accepted.

But requests is still throwing :

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): saturn-api-h.euronext.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 441, in wrap_socket
cnx.do_handshake()
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1806, in do_handshake
self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1546, in _raise_ssl_error
_raise_current_error()
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]
```

What I did try to solve the issue :

- Follow the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)
- Update requests module to 2.18.4
- Install pyOpenSSL 17.5.0
- Check the .crt/.pem formating
- Curl tests

**Working curl:**

```
curl -i -vvv -X POST https://saturn-api-h.euronext.com/SaturnWebServices/rest/Authentication/AuthenticateUser -H "Content-Type: application/json" --cert ./client.crt --cacert ./digicert-full-chain.crt
```

With a valid Authorization headers it return a 200 status code, without it 401 "Access denied!". If the certificate validation fails, it redirects to [euronext.com](http://www.euronext.com) with status code 302.

**Problematic python:**

```
endpoint = 'https://saturn-api-h.euronext.com/SaturnWebServices/rest/Authentication/AuthenticateUser'       
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', } #'Authorization': 'Basic <auth_string>',

r = requests.post(endpoint, headers = headers, verify = './digicert-full-chain.crt', cert = './client.crt')
```

**Certificates:**

- **digicert-full-chain.crt** is containing the full chain from DigiCert:

  - DigiCertAssuredIDRootCA.pem
  - DigiCertSHA2AssuredIDCA.pem
  - DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.pem
- **client.crt** is containg our certificate and its key.

Why is curl command working whereas python's requests module is failling?

Is there any way to show the complete handshake process from the requests module?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem myself, a certificate was missing from the full chain.

Doing `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/certifi/cacert.pem > certifi-digicert.pem; digicert-full-chain.pem >> certifi-digicert.pem` and passing the resulting certificate to the verify argument worked.

As a side note, I used the strace command to compare certificate locations from both python and curl:

- `strace <python_command> |& grep open | grep -E 'crt|pem'`
- `strace <curl_command> |& grep open | grep -E 'crt|pem'`

I also checked with Wireshark to get the full handshake process, the pyOpenSSL module was getting an error after the server's Certificate Request. `Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unknown CA)`.