# Identifying and breaking on exception: 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error' using python's requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, python-requests

I'm currently parsing through a list of URLs and in the event that one throws an exception I want to just break and move on to the next one.

However, I keeping getting

```
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]
```

Solving this exception is beyond my expertise right now, so I want to just be able to skip it for now and handle that later. My problem, however, is when I write the try catch to do so:

```
    try:
        r = requests_retry_session(session=s).get(test_link, verify=cafile, allow_redirects=True, timeout=4.0)

    except OpenSSL.SSL.Error:
        print('SSL error, moving to next domain')
        break
```

I get this:

```
NameError: name 'OpenSSL' is not defined
```

I know the easiest way to fix this would be to just do `verify=False`, however, tthat'svery unsafe and I would rather not open myself up to a possible MITM attack.

What I've tried:

Attempting to [follow the documentation of this previous related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49861597/requests-module-throwing-openssl-ssl-error):

```
pip install --upgrade certifi
```

And finally an extremely sloppy try catch block, that essentially catches `NameError: name 'OpenSSL' is not defined` and breaks on that as a name error, which is not pythonic at all. I know I can do a very general catch all, however, I don't want to skip all errors.

I'm running python 3.7.3 and requests 2.22.0

Comment: can you tell me which website are you trying to access?

Comment: `NameError: name 'OpenSSL' is not defined` - did you remember about `import OpenSSL`? ;) Also, if you run each request as thread, exception will just kill the thread and you can easily discard killed results.

Comment: @h4z3 running that now, I've been able to parse through a couple domains before I hit the error so I wouldn't image (I think?) that would be the problem.

Comment: @LucasWieloch I'm running it again to get you which domain it is, it takes a second. update: this is the domain  http://www.4mresearch.com/

Answer (score 1):

> Attempting to [follow the documentation of this previous related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49861597/requests-module-throwing-openssl-ssl-error)

You should have solved this exception handling by following those instructions and having `pyopenssl` (`pip install pyopenssl`) installed and its `OpenSSL` imported at the top of your module.

Comment: I edited my answer, it's about handling the exception, we have no enough data to deal with the actual error.

Answer (score 1):

Found the correct exception, its super trivial but confusing documentation.

So `OpenSSL.SSL.Error` would be caught by using `requests.exceptions.SSLError`, and importing OpenSSL or pyOpenSSL doesn't need to be done (explicitly) in this case.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a tidy way to handle this.  I get an exception thrown when I call `load_certificate` and I can't catch it with `OpenSSL.SSL.Error`.